# How to access DirectivesModule from a component which uses some of the directive inside?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-modules

*Edited*: The proposed solution is the right one, I had to mention  that `SharedModule` has to be imported into the parent component of the child component which uses DropDownDirective in order to work.
I'm working on Angular 4 application and I wanted to optimize its structure using `SharedModule` which containes `DirectivesModule`. I have a component X which uses one of the directives from `DirectivesModule` by importing `SharedModule` in it, like so:

app/X.component.ts

---

```
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
```

And in the view of the component X I'm using the directive like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-5 dropdown" appDropDown>
```

The structure of the app is following:

```
root
  -- X.component.ts
  -- shared
     -- shared.module.ts
     -- directives
        -- directives.module.ts
        -- dropdown.directive.ts
```

What am I doing, is importing DirectivesModule into SharedModule, like so:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DirectivesModule } from './directives/directives.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
    DirectivesModule
  ]
 })
 export class SharedModule { }
```

DirectivesModule imports and exports DropDownDirective like so:

```
   import { DropDownDirective } from './dropdown.directive';
   .....
    exports: [
     DropDownDirective,
   ]
```

And, then `SharedModule` is imported into X.component by the aforenamed way. 
The problem is that the directive doesn't work. It should apply a class 'open' to the element but doesn't do it.
I am not sure if this is the correct way to implement the structure, so suggested changes are welcome and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DirectivesModule`  into your imports

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DirectivesModule
  ], 
......
```

Comment: Yes, finally I saw where my mistake was - thank you!